# Pandas not filtering on basis of basis of a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have had success in filtering the column values however for this dataframe the filter is returning a NaN dataframe after filter.  I am not sure where I am wrong. I am posting the codes with results.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("http://portal.amfiindia.com/DownloadNAVHistoryReport_Po.aspx?mf=17&tp=1&frmdt=04-Nov-2017&todt=02-Dec-2018",sep=";",parse_dates=['Date'])
df=df.drop(['Repurchase Price','Sale Price'],axis=1)
df = df.dropna()
df['Net Asset Value'] = df['Net Asset Value'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
df.columns = [['scheme_code','scheme','nav','date']]
df[df['scheme_code'] == '123690']
```

The result of the filter is

```
      scheme_code scheme                  nav date
2          123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
3          123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
4          123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
5          123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
6          123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
7          123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
8          123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
9          123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
10         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
11         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
12         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
13         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
14         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
15         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
16         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
17         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
18         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
19         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
20         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
21         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
22         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
23         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
24         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
25         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
26         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
27         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
28         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
29         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
30         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
31         123690    NaN                  nan  NaT
```

However if I look at the dataframe head method I can see the actual data with values

```
  scheme_code                               scheme                  nav  \
2      123690  Kotak Banking and PSU Debt - Growth                38.60   
3      123690  Kotak Banking and PSU Debt - Growth                38.58   
4      123690  Kotak Banking and PSU Debt - Growth                38.58   
5      123690  Kotak Banking and PSU Debt - Growth                38.59   
6      123690  Kotak Banking and PSU Debt - Growth                38.59   

        date  
2 2017-11-06  
3 2017-11-07  
4 2017-11-08  
5 2017-11-09
```

I also tried to convert to numeric, still I can see the same result. I would appreciate if someone can help me to figure out what is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specify the columns as a list of a list (note the double brackets), so the condition is not met. Just change it to a simple list:

```
df.columns = ['scheme_code','scheme','nav','date']
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been scratching my head since morning.